# How to format a number as a currency using a currency code (ISO 4217)

Tags: android, locale, number-formatting, currency-formatting

My API returns an [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) currency code consisting of three letters, for example `USD`, `JPY` or `GDP`.
The `NumberFormat` class takes a `Locale`, which in turn takes a *country* code.
How can I format a number using only the *currency* code?

I Cannot use the NumberFormatt**er** class since it requires min_sdk 30 and I run min_sdk 21.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but i think you cannot. EUR: we have countries which uses `,` and countries with `.` as decimal point, so EUR do not uniquely define a currency format.

Comment: I found a way to do it using the Currency class, but as you say it does not convert it into country specific formats. This would be fine since I'm working on a bank app, and you just want the generic currency format (think currency exchange services). However in sweden, which is the target market, it returns `SEK1234` when you would want `1234 kr`.  
I will update with an answer once I get it to work!